# Django jquery form submissions returning 500

Tags: django, jquery, django-forms

I am trying to do a modelform submission is Django with jquery and I am getting a 500 server response and not sure how to proceed.

This is my js:

```
function addUpdate(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = jQuery(e.target);
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(){
            $('<p>Been Added</p>').insertBefore("div.tr-list");
        }
    });
};

jQuery("form#tr-form").submit(function(e){
    addUpdate(e);
});
```

This is my form:

```
<input class="nidden" type="button" id="tr-trigger" value="Add Resource" />

    <form class="absolute" id="tr-form" action="{% url topic_resource_create topic.person.user topic.slug %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
    <div id="tr-wrapper">
        {{ tr_form.as_p }}

        <input id="tr-submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

This is my view:

```
def tr_create_xhr(request, slug):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TopicResourceForm(request.POST)
        try:
            r = Resource.objects.get(url=form.cleaned_data['resource'])
        except Resource.DoesNotExist:
            r = Resource.objects.create(url=form.cleaned_data['resource'], rtype=form.cleaned_data['rtype'])
            r.save()
        form.resource = r
        topic = Topic.objects.get(person__user=request.user, slug__iexact=slug)
        form.topic = topic
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        response = serializers.serialize('json', form)

    if request.is_ajax():
        return HttpResponse(response, content_type="application/javascript")
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("../..")
```

I am not sure if they view logic is correct because I get a 500 server error everytime i try and post to the url. I have a couple other similar form submissions that are giving me the same error.

Comment: Get firefox + firebug or chrome + dev tools, and look at the 500 response.

Comment: I am doing that but its not telling me anyhting besides 500 server response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug should show you the actual error. However, in this case it seems likely that the problem is in your serialization code. You can't call `serializers.serialize` on a *form* - that makes no sense at all. The serializers work on a queryset.

What you need to do is get the object returned from saving the form, wrap that in a list, and then serialize it:

```
obj = form.save()
response = serializers.serialize('json', [obj])
```

However you also have some issues with the flow through your view - there's no object if the form is not valid, for example.

Comment: Thanks, but my form is the object being created no? Or the object is created/returned only when I call save on the form? Does serialize require more than one object? In firebug I see the full error message and sure enough lots of problems in the view, thanks for the insight.

Comment: No, your form is a form. The object being created, which you want to serialize, is a model instance. Serializers only work on sets of model instances.

Answer (score 0):

usually means can't find jquery files. look at the source of your html header. should be something like this and if you follow the link you should see the jquery script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```

your base template would have something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```

You may also find the [documentation on static](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) files useful.

Comment: Other classes are being applied with jQuery so i do not think that is it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of csrf-protection? Symptoms are very similar.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/

So you can try to add `{% csrf_token %}` somewhere between `<form>` and `</form>` tags.

Comment: I have that as well. It appears as if the data is being sent to the server as 'text/html', is that correct?

Comment: One more thing: you have url `{% url topic_resource_create topic.person.user topic.slug %}`, but your view does have only 1 parameter `slug`: `def tr_create_xhr(request, slug):`

Comment: Didnt help, i noticed that before. Does the view need to be passed all of the keyword parameters from the url?